# Solidity code Error

Tags: solidity, remix

### # Solidity Transaction code Error

### Solidity Code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.4 <0.6.0;



contract PetSharing {




    //마스터(러브펫) 지갑 
    struct LovePet {
        address lovepet;
        uint lovepetwallet;
    }



    mapping (address => LovePet) LovePeter;

    // 펫주인의 정보
    struct Owner {
        address owner;
        string ownerName;
        string petName;
        uint ownerprice;
        string petInfo;
        string petselltext;
        uint ownerwallet;
    }


    mapping (address => Owner) Owners;
    address[] public OwnerAddresses;

    //펫주인의 펫인증 이미지들
    struct Image {
        string petImageHash;
        string ipfsInfo;
    }

    mapping (address => Image[]) private images;

    //펫시터 정보들
    struct PetSitter {
        address petsitter;
        string petSittername;
        string petSitterInfo;
        string educationConfirm;
        string petsharetext;
        uint sitterprice;
        uint petsitterwallet;
    }

    mapping (address => PetSitter) PetSitters;
    address[] public PetSitterAddresses;

/*   constructor(address _MASTER) public {

       LovePeter[_MASTER].lovepet = msg.sender;

     } */

    //마스터 확인
    modifier MasterInfo(address _MASTER) {
        require(_MASTER == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    //펫주인 확인 
    modifier OwnerModifyInfo(address _OWNER ) {
        require(_OWNER == msg.sender);
        _;

    }

    //펫시터 확인
    modifier PetSitterModifyInfo(address _PETSITTER) {
        require(_PETSITTER == msg.sender);
        _;

    }

    //master 
    function RegisterMaster(address _master) public {
        LovePeter[_master].lovepet = _master;
    }

    //펫주인 등록
    function RegisterOwner(address _owner, string _ownername, string _petname, string _petInfo) public  {
         //   var Owner = Owners[_owner];

            Owners[_owner].ownerName = _ownername;
            Owners[_owner].petName = _petname;
            Owners[_owner].petInfo = _petInfo;

            OwnerAddresses.push(_owner);

    }

    //펫시터 등록
    function RegisterPetsitter(address _petsitter, string _petsittername, string _petsitterinfo, string _education) public  {
     //  var PetSitter = PetSitters[_petsitter];

        PetSitters[_petsitter].petSittername = _petsittername;
        PetSitters[_petsitter].petSitterInfo = _petsitterinfo;
        PetSitters[_petsitter].educationConfirm = _education;

        PetSitterAddresses.push(_petsitter);
    }

    //펫주인들의 목록
    function getOwnerAddresses() view public returns (address[]) {
        return OwnerAddresses;
    }

    //펫 주인의 정보들
    function getOwnerInfo(address _owner) view public returns (string,string,string) {
        return(Owners[_owner].ownerName,Owners[_owner].petName,Owners[_owner].petInfo);
    }

    //펫 주인 숫자
    function OwnerCount() view public returns (uint) {
        return OwnerAddresses.length;
    }

    //펫시터들의 목록
    function getPetSitterAddresses() view public returns (address[]) {
        return PetSitterAddresses;
    }

    //펫시터들의 정보
    function getPetSitterInfo(address _petsitter) view public returns(string,string,string) {
        return (PetSitters[_petsitter].petSittername, PetSitters[_petsitter].petSitterInfo, PetSitters[_petsitter].educationConfirm);
    }

    //펫시터 숫자
    function PetSitterCount() view public returns (uint) {
        return PetSitterAddresses.length;
    }

    //펫 인증 정보를 블록체인 등록
    function uploadImage(string hash, string ipfs) public {
        images[msg.sender].push(Image(hash,ipfs));
    }

    //펫시터 돌봄서비스 글 등록
    function PetSitterShareText(address _PETSITTER, string _petsittertext)  PetSitterModifyInfo(_PETSITTER) public view returns(string) {
      //  var PetSitter = PetSitters[_sitter];
       _petsittertext  = PetSitters[_PETSITTER].petsharetext;
        return "정상적으로 등록되었습니다";
    }

    //오너 돌봄서비스 요청글 등록
    function OwnerShareText(address _OWNER, string _ownersharetext) OwnerModifyInfo(_OWNER) public view  returns(string){
        _ownersharetext = Owners[_OWNER].petselltext;
        return "정상적으로 등록되었습니다";
    } 

    //강아지 돌봄서비스 거래 (펫주인이 펫시터글 선택 했을때 or 펫시터가 펫주인글을 선택했을때)
    function TransactionPet(address _petsitter,address _OWNER )  OwnerModifyInfo(_OWNER) public payable {
        require(PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet >= PetSitters[_petsitter].sitterprice);
        require(PetSitters[_petsitter].sitterprice == msg.value);
    }


    //펫주인이 돌봄이 힘들때 펫시터에게 강아지를 판매 할때
   function PetChangeTransaction(address _ownerseller, address _PETSITTER, address _MASTER, uint _ownerpirce) MasterInfo(_MASTER) PetSitterModifyInfo(_PETSITTER) public  payable {
       // var Owner = Owners[_seller];
       _ownerpirce = Owners[_ownerseller].ownerprice;
    //   require(PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet >= Owners[_ownerseller].ownerprice);
       require(_ownerpirce == msg.value);
       PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet -= _ownerpirce;
       require(PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet + _ownerpirce >= PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet);
       require(LovePeter[_MASTER].lovepetwallet + _ownerpirce >= LovePeter[_MASTER].lovepetwallet);
       LovePeter[_MASTER].lovepetwallet += msg.value;
    }

    function PetChange(address _ownerseller, address _PETSITTER, address _MASTER, uint _ownerpirce) MasterInfo(_MASTER) PetSitterModifyInfo(_PETSITTER) public {
        _ownerpirce = Owners[_ownerseller].ownerprice;
        LovePeter[msg.sender].lovepetwallet -= _ownerpirce;
        require(Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet + _ownerpirce >= Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet);

       Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet += msg.value;
        Owners[_ownerseller].owner = PetSitters[_PETSITTER].petsitter;
    }
     function test(address _OWNER) OwnerModifyInfo(_OWNER) public view  returns(uint){

        return  Owners[_OWNER].ownerwallet;
    }

    function test2(address _MASTER) MasterInfo(_MASTER) public view  returns(uint){

        return LovePeter[_MASTER].lovepetwallet;
    }
}
```

- The error message is

> "Transaction to PetSharing.PetChangeTransaction Error: VM error:
>   revert. reverse The transaction has been exceeded to the initial
>   state. Note: The constructor could be paid if you send value."

How do I fix the error?

## There are more questions. Please watch.

```
 function PetChangeTransaction( address _PETSITTER, address _master, uint _ownerpirce ) PetSitterModifyInfo(_PETSITTER) public  payable {
       // var Owner = Owners[_seller];
       require(PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet >= _ownerpirce);
       require(_ownerpirce == msg.value);
       PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet -= _ownerpirce;
       require(PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet + _ownerpirce >= PetSitters[msg.sender].petsitterwallet);
       require(LovePeter[_master].lovepetwallet + _ownerpirce >= LovePeter[_master].lovepetwallet);
       LovePeter[_master].lovepetwallet += msg.value;
    }

    function PetChange(address _ownerseller, address _petsitter, address _MASTER, uint _ownerpirce) MasterInfo(_MASTER) public {
        LovePeter[msg.sender].lovepetwallet -= _ownerpirce;
        require(Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet + _ownerpirce >= Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet);
        Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet += _ownerpirce;
        Owners[_ownerseller].owner = PetSitters[_petsitter].petsitter;
    }
```

There are no errors when compiling, but if you modify the code below, Warning will occur. Why does the `PetChange` function Warning occur when it does not differ from the msg,value in the `PetChangeTransaction` function above?

```
 function PetChange(address _ownerseller, address _petsitter, address _MASTER, uint _ownerpirce) MasterInfo(_MASTER) public {
         require(_ownerpirce == msg.value);
        LovePeter[msg.sender].lovepetwallet -= _ownerpirce;
        require(Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet + _ownerpirce >= Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet);
        Owners[_ownerseller].ownerwallet += msg.value;
        Owners[_ownerseller].owner = PetSitters[_petsitter].petsitter;
    }
```

- Warning is

> browser/ballot.sol:178:33: Warning: "msg.value" used in non-payable
>   function. Do you want to add the "payable" modifier to this function?

Answer (score 1):

Your original question's error message is impossible and I assume it was copypasted wrong or something similar. Your append's picture shows the real error message.

Anyway, as Rick mentioned, the end part of the error message is just a guess (and usually a wrong guess). But the beginning of it is the important part: `Transaction to PetSharing.PetChangeTransaction Error: VM error: revert`. This tells you that the transaction was reverted.

Usually the transaction gets reverted due to some `require` statement not passing. So I suggest you go through all your `require` statements which get triggered with that function call and figure out which one causes the error. You can either try to debug the transaction or just comment out the `require` statements one by one and see when the error disappears.

Comment: Thank you so much. I sucess about This problem. It's by your favor.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to try to write on one of the cited function argument:

```
_ownerpirce = Owners[_ownerseller].ownerprice;
```

The error message you reported is unrelated: it is a guess of the compiler, which did not understand the situation, and so it results wrong.

EDIT

Looking at your code I find a lot of require strictly related to the value of that poor _ownerpirce. I suspect that they cannot pass because it’s value is not that you seems to need.

If should this fix don’t work alone (do not write on function arguments !) do a simple thing: comment out every require or assert in your function for a test and try again. If this work, reinsert them all one by one in order to find the problem.

Some variable is needed to be used instead your poor _ownerpirce!

Comment: When I saw Rick Park's answer, I commented on the part, but the error was the same.

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I sucess about This problem. It's by your favor.

Comment: I added a question. Can you watch it again?

Comment: According to the rules you should mark as answered this question and open another one. Do it and I’ll try to help.

Comment: Please feel free to upvote all comments and answer which helped